# Alternative for `return await …` for the cases when waiting for some result which must be returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I know that ESLint/TSLint rulest cannot be "right" for 100% of situations. However I need to decide which rules I really don't need.

In ElectonJS, it's not recommended to use Node.js modules in Renderer Process. Instead, Renderer process should send request to Main Process and listen for the response. Below TypeScript class takes care about this routine. (I hope my variable names make code does not need comments, but those are hard to understand, please let me to know in comments)

```js
import { ipcRenderer as IpcRenderer } from "electron";

import InterProcessDataTransferProtocol from "@ProjectInitializer:Root/InterProcessDataTransferProtocol";
import CheckingPathForWriteAccess = InterProcessDataTransferProtocol.CheckingPathForWriteAccess;
import MainProcessEvents = InterProcessDataTransferProtocol.MainProcessEvents;

import Timeout = NodeJS.Timeout;


export default abstract class InterProcessFacilitator {

  private static readonly IS_PATH_WRITABLE__RESPONSE_WAITING_PERIOD__MILLISECONDS: number = 10000;

  public static async requestCheckingPathForAccessToWrite(targetPath: string): Promise<boolean> {

    IpcRenderer.send(
        InterProcessDataTransferProtocol.RendererProcessEvents.checkingPathForWriteAccessRequestSent,
        { targetPath }
    );

    const responseWaitingTimeout: Timeout = setTimeout(
        () => { throw new Error("No response from Main Process"); },
        InterProcessFacilitator.IS_PATH_WRITABLE__RESPONSE_WAITING_PERIOD__MILLISECONDS
    );

    return await new Promise<boolean>((resolve: (isWritable: boolean) => void): void => {
      IpcRenderer.on(
          MainProcessEvents.checkingPathForWriteAccessDone,
          (_event: Electron.Event, responsePayload: CheckingPathForWriteAccess.ResponsePayload) =>
          {
            clearTimeout(responseWaitingTimeout);
            if (responsePayload.targetPath === targetPath) {
              resolve(responsePayload.isWritable);
            }
          });
    });
  }
}
```

Currently, method `requestCheckingPathForAccessToWrite` violates [no-return-await](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await), the ESLint rules. However it could be used as:

```
async function checkTheDefaultPathForWrightPermission(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const pickedPathIsWritable: boolean = await InterProcessFacilitator
              .requestCheckingPathForAccessToWrite(DEFAULT_PATH);
      pickedPathIsWritable ?
          this.relatedStoreModule.reportAboutUnableToWriteToDirectoryErrorResolution() :
          this.relatedStoreModule.reportAboutUnableToWriteToDirectoryErrorOccurrence();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`unable to check wright permission for path ${DEFAULT_PATH}`);
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

From ESLint documentation:

> Inside an async function, return await is seldom useful. Since the
>   return value of an async function is always wrapped in
>   Promise.resolve, return await doesn’t actually do anything except add
>   extra time before the overarching Promise resolves or rejects. The
>   only valid exception is if return await is used in a try/catch
>   statement to catch errors from another Promise-based function.

Can you criticize either my solution or this ESLint rule, and in first case, suggest the refactoring?

Comment: Because it's not being caught in the same block, can't you just return the Promise? Just remove the `await`? I'd *think* that would result in the same behavior as in your current code

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thank you for the answer. You right, `await` is needless here. And also this case is another prove that [require-await](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await) rule is obstacle.